# how to clear all map overlays or markers from google map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to clear all map overlays or markers from google map and using following code

```
if(!mapOverlays.isEmpty())
     {
     mapOverlays.clear();

 }
```

which is giving me exception can any one guide me?
am i right or wrong if i am wrong then kindly provide me the solution to my problem.

i want map clean if there is any marker on it.

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: actually after running above code when click on map or an overlay then all the overlays disappears. am i missing something? mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    if(!mapOverlays.isEmpty()) 
       { 
       mapOverlays.clear(); 
   
       }

Comment: i want to remove all overlays without clicking on map..

Comment: Wow, spent a couple hours trying until I found this thread, thanks much, and hope the docs/tuts on the G API were more clear. Or maybe if they had some web 2.0 right there (like PHP.net)...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
mapView.invalidate();
```

i was missing to update map. now working fine. so the whole code look like

```
if(!mapOverlays.isEmpty()) 
     { 
     mapOverlays.clear(); 
     mapView.invalidate();

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to entirely clear map overlays you'd need to clear ListArray in class that extends ItemizedOverlay.

Something like this:

```
    mItemizedOverlay.clearOverlays();
    mMapView.getOverlays().clear();
    mMapView.invalidate();
```